# get html form value using jquery through selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, selector

```
<form id="Task1_1_1">
    Keywords: <input type="text" name="twitKey" value="iphone"><br><br> 
    Coordinates: <input type="text" name="twitLoc" value=""><br> <br> 
    Scope: <input type="text" name="scope" value="10" > km<br> <br>
    <button id="sendButton1_1_1">Search</button>
</form>
```

This is the form. I can get the values of the form through the following code.

```
$('#sendButton1_1_1').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log($('#Task1_1_1').val());
});
```

Here is the output from the js console

```
twitKey=iphone&twitLoc=&scope=10
```

My question is how to get the value of twitKey by using selectors?
Or do I have to parse myself?
I already know I get value by id 
[Get the value from HTML form using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159392/get-the-value-from-html-form-using-jquery)

I want to know whether I can get the value from value name such as

```
name="twitKey"
```

Comment: input[name='twitkey']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with -

```
console.log($('form#Task1_1_1 input[name=twitKey]').val());
```

Add a class/id to it -

```
<input type="text" name="twitKey" id="twitKey" value="iphone" >
```

And JS - `console.log($('#twitKey').val());`

Comment: If I use the first way, Is there any method that can ensure input[name=twitKey] come from the form with id"Task1_1_1"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet with multiple ways to grab the value of twitKey:

```js
$('input[name="twitKey"]').val(); //iphone
$('input:first').val(); //iphone
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="Task1_1_1">
    Keywords: <input type="text" name="twitKey" value="iphone"><br><br> 
    Coordinates: <input type="text" name="twitLoc" value=""><br> <br> 
    Scope: <input type="text" name="scope" value="10" > km<br> <br>
    <button id="sendButton1_1_1">Search</button>
</form>
```